# dn-based linux groups from ldap

Tags: ldap, linux, openldap, groups

Is there any way to use one of LDAP's DN-based groups for linux groups instead of using the uid-based posixGroup objectclass?

More broadly, is there any way I can avoid having one set of groups for supporting linux accounts and a parallel set of groups that's used by everything else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

In your nss_ldap configuration file, set nss_schema:

```
nss_schema rfc2307bis
```

On your server in the schema, make sure the posixGroup object class is auxiliary instead of structural.

Then you can use both the groupofmembers(new) or groupofnames(old) and posixgroup objectclasses for each group. Each member will be in a member attribute:

```
dn: cn=foo,ou=Groups,dc=example
objectclass: top
objectclass: posixgroup
objectclass: groupofmembers
gidnumber: 9234
member: uid=bob,ou=people,dc=example
member: uid=alice,ou=people,dc=example
```

Comment: had to add `groupOfMembers` to my schema manually and add `nss_map_attribute uniqueMember member` but I got it working.  Now I'm stuck on nested groups, know anything about that?

Comment: Nevermind, it started working.  I think I probably had just some bogus values that were messing things up.

Comment: Because it cost me some time to find this: At least in current Debian (11), the nss_ldap configuration file is located at `/etc/libnss-ldap.conf` (see [manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/libnss-ldap/libnss-ldap.conf.5.en.html)). In my case, I had to create it first.

Answer (score 3):

To get the `groupOfMembers` schema, you can either [extract it from the rfc](http://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-howard-rfc2307bis-02.txt), or use [this one](http://dev.gentoo.org/~robbat2/distfiles/rfc2307bis.schema-20120525) that's been done for you, and save it to `/etc/openldap/schema/rfc2307bis.schema`. This schema supersedes the `nis` schema, so remove that one first.

#### If you're using the `cn=config` backend

1. create a file `convert-schema.conf` containing

   ```
   include /etc/openldap/schema/core.schema
   include /etc/openldap/schema/cosine.schema
   include /etc/openldap/schema/rfc2307bis.schema
   ```
2. create a directory called `/tmp/converted`
3. convert schema to ldif: `slaptest -f convert-schema.conf -F /tmp/convert/`

   - Fix any errors, including removing apostrophes in values and removing references to the authPassword attribute until `slaptest` succeeds

   copy `/tmp/convert/cn=config/cn=schema/cn={2}rfc2307bis.ldif` to `/etc/openldap/rfc2307bis.ldif`

   modify `rfc2307bis.ldif`

   - change the first line to `dn: cn=rfc2307bis,cn=schema,cn=config`
   - change the third line to `cn: rfc2307bis`
   - remove the seven lines at the end (`structuralObjectClass` through `modifyTimestamp`)

   import the schema ldif:
   `ldapadd -f rfc2307bis.ldif -D "cn=admin,cn=config" -W`

Comment: Note that the extracted schema file is NOT directly importable in OpenLDAP 2.4, some edits need to be made. My updated version is found at https://github.com/shoop/openldap-rfc2307bis/blob/master/rfc2307bis.schema