# openLDAP how to remove the nis schema from the current configuration

Tags: openldap, schema

openLDAP 2.4
Ubuntu 14.04

I have found this question [dn-based linux groups from ldap](https://serverfault.com/questions/224750/dn-based-linux-groups-from-ldap?newreg=8570475e81ca4058bf4303216414c6de). I am trying to include the rfc2307bis schema, but it seems the nis schema must be removed from the configuration before including rfc2307bis. How can I remove this nis schema from the current configuration?

Answer (score 6):

I have managed to get it working:

1. `sudo service slapd stop`
2. `sudo slapcat -n0 > ~/config.ldif` (configuration backup)
3. `sudo slapcat -n1 > ~/users.ldif` (users and groups backup)
4. delete the contents of the folder `/etc/ldap/slapd.d` (or rename and create a new `slapd.d` folder)
5. delete the contents of the folder `/var/lib/ldap` (or rename and create a new `ldap` folder), I didn't delete just one file `DB_CONFIG`
6. modify `~/config.ldif` file to delete the `nis` schema
7. `sudo slapadd -F /etc/ldap/slapd.d -n 0 -l ~/config.ldif`
8. `sudo chown openldap:openldap -R /etc/ldap/slapd.d`
9. `sudo service slapd start`
10. add `rfc2307bis` schema to the ldap configuration:

    ```
    sudo ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// \
        -f /etc/ldap/schema/rfc2307bis.ldif -D "cn=admin,cn=config" -W
    ```
11. `sudo service slapd stop`
12. modify `~/users.ldif`:

    - add `objectClass: groupOfMembers` to group objects
    - remove lines with the `structuralObjectClass` (or just replace the string `structuralObjectClass: posixGroup` with the string `objectClass: groupOfMembers`)

    It should look like this (for group objects only):

    ```
    dn: cn=groupname,ou=Groups,dc=some,dc=net
    cn: groupname
    gidNumber: 501
    objectClass: posixGroup
    objectClass: groupOfMembers
    objectClass: top
    description: some description
    entryUUID: f4599276-d798-1033-80a3-b52a8483a973
    creatorsName: cn=admin,dc=some,dc=net
    createTimestamp: 20140923181242Z
    memberUid: peterb
    memberUid: kennyg
    memberUid: mendyn
    entryCSN: 20140925190322.990791Z#000000#000#000000
    modifiersName: cn=admin,dc=some,dc=net
    modifyTimestamp: 20140925190322Z
    ```
13. `sudo slapadd -F /etc/ldap/slapd.d -n 1 -l ~/users.ldif`
14. `sudo chown openldap:openldap -R /var/lib/ldap`
15. `sudo service slapd start`

Comment: Could you explain what needs to be done in: `modify ~/config.ldif file to delete the nis schema` step ?